# Accion response calculation on tilt steering kick board scooter

Tags: rigid-body-dynamics, solid-mechanics

Hi I am designing a home made kick board scooter, need to understant
the behaviour between the board angle and the turn angle.

In a classic sakateboard the foot action is transformed to turn angle,
following the next formula, taked from the paper:

"Stability of damped skateboards under human control", 
Balazs Varszegi, Denes Takacs, Gabor Stepan

tan(turn_angle)=tan(truck_angle)*sin(board_angle)

Then if plot the board_angle to final_angle relation,
the relation is lineal (for truck_angle of 40-45 degress).
[image]
Then i want to calculate the relation for a kick board scooter showed 
in the next image.

[image]

How can find the equation ?

For a given main axe length an wheel arm length.

Greetings